# Splitting a binary tree into two halves

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

I am looking to prove the following:

> Each binary tree with $n \ge 2$ nodes has an edge whose removal results in two trees, each having at most $\lceil (2n-1)/3 \rceil$ nodes.

I am not sure how to approach this, or find some way to detect such an edge. Would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 3):

Root the binary tree at an arbitrary node. Starting at the root, go down the tree, always choosing the node whose subtree is larger, until reaching a node $v$ whose subtree contains at most $\lceil (2n-1)/3 \rceil$ nodes. Remove the edge between the node and its parent.

By construction, the subtree rooted at the parent of $v$ contains $m > \lceil (2n-1)/3 \rceil$ nodes. Since when going down we always choose the node whose subtree is larger, this means that the subtree rooted at $v$ contains at least $(m-1)/2$ nodes, and so the rest of the tree contains at most this many nodes:
$$
n - \frac{m-1}{2} \leq n - 1 -\frac{\lceil (2n-1)/3 \rceil}{2}.
$$
The right-hand side ought to be bounded by $\lceil (2n-1)/3 \rceil$.