# Find balanced edge of a binary tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

What algorithm can be used to find a balanced edge in a binary tree? If we remove that particular edge, the tree is split up nearly equally.
Each tree will have at most $\lceil{(2n-1)/3}\rceil$ nodes.

Comment: @steven I have added the definition of balanced edge. It will split tree into two trees with  each having maximum nodes as given the OP

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of: [Splitting a binary tree into two halves](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144928/splitting-a-binary-tree-into-two-halves), whose answer by Yuval Filmus is constructive and immediately provides a linear-time algorithm.